# Data types in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I am developing a json parser to xml using xslt transformer, thatis the output is type text. However does not provide the output data types.
For example, the input xml has data that are string or int or date, and the xslt does not realize what kind they are and parse them all the same.
My query is whether there is any way to import a xsd file (has the data types) within a xslt, xsd then you can check for the type of data and transform Finar accordingly.

From already thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There's a fair amount you can do with a schema-aware XSLT 2.0 transformation, but I'm not sure I understand the requirement sufficiently well to say which facilities are relevant.

You say you are converting JSON to XML, but you say the output is text. I would have thought that the transformation was text in, XML out.

You say "However does not provide the output data types". There's a missing subject to this sentence. Where do you expect the data type knowledge to come from? Are you parsing a very specific JSON input whose structure is known to your stylesheet, or are you parsing arbitrary JSON?

And I've no idea what "Finar" is, or where it fits in!

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry for the delay.

What I meant is this:

1) I have an xml file as input.
2) I have as output a json file.

To go from xml to json use a xslt file in which I travel the xml and json file form.
When I meant to type text I meant json output. This is so because there is no direct transformation xml to json, but "model" output to meet the standards of the nomenclature json.

Thanks for responding!